# search engine in laravel not working

Tags: api, search, laravel-5, search-engine

i am trying to implement Smart Search Engine Here is the Tutorial link
https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-smart-search
i know this Tutorial for Laravel 4 and I am Tying to implement in Laravel 5.2
Now i Stuck
i can't get json format of api/search

Here is my Route

```
Route::get('api/search', 'ApiSearchController@index');
```

Here is Controller Which i Create with the Helper of Artisan in App/http/controller i did try to create like tutorial api/searchcontroller but its won't work always getting error "ApiSearchController@index Not found"

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Product;
use Response;

class ApiSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function appendValue($data, $type, $element)
    {
        // operate on the item passed by reference, adding the element and type
        foreach ($data as $key => & $item) {
            $item[$element] = $type;
        }
        return $data;   

    }

    public function appendURL($data, $prefix)
    {
        // operate on the item passed by reference, adding the url based on slug
        foreach ($data as $key => & $item) {
            $item['url'] = url($prefix.'/'.$item['slug']);
        }
        return $data;       
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $query = e(Input::get('q',''));

        if(!$query && $query == '') return Response::json(array(), 400);

        $products = Product::where('published', true)
            ->where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get(array('slug','name','icon'))->toArray();

        $categories = Category::where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')
            ->has('products')
            ->take(5)
            ->get(array('slug', 'name'))
            ->toArray();

        // Data normalization
        $categories = $this->appendValue($categories, url('img/icons/category-icon.png'),'icon');

        $products   = $this->appendURL($products, 'products');
        $categories  = $this->appendURL($categories, 'categories');

        // Add type of data to each item of each set of results
        $products = $this->appendValue($products, 'product', 'class');
        $categories = $this->appendValue($categories, 'category', 'class');

        // Merge all data into one array
        $data = array_merge($products, $categories);

        return Response::json(array(
            'data'=>$data
        ));
    }
}
```

when i open http://localhost/search/public/api/search
i should be get all data from database like Tutorial
But can't get 
other thing is same
Please Show me What's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search isn't working as it is expecting to be provided with a query to search for as part of a query string or request.

`Input::get('q')` is saying to retrieve `q` from your query string or request and use it for the search.

When you go to the page `http://localhost/search/public/api/search` you are doing so as a `GET` request and so would need to provide your query like so `http://localhost/search/public/api/search?q=example`.

The example in the tutorial is using AJAX to run a `GET` request which does the above for you.

Try adding `?q=xxxx` on to the end of your URL and it should work if you have set it up appropriately following that tutorial.

Comment: Yes so why its not searching on my / page
here is my home Page input
<select id="searchbox" name="q" placeholder="Search products or categories..." class="form-control"></select>

Comment: You can check what is being sent in your ajax request using the network tab of your developer tools

Comment: how to provide a query for it to search

Comment: do i need more modification because i am new in laravel if you show me what i do it will  be very help full Thank you

Comment: wow Thanks James i found api error i fix 2 error 
but This Error
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products()
what do i now

Comment: You have an incomplete Eloquent query somewhere...It doesn't look to be in your controller above though. Can you post your `Products` model?

Comment: its blank 
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
 
}